# Will I be able to make video calls over Skype with ACME Tablet TB01?

Tags: skype

I want to buy [ACME Tablet TB01](http://laptopstops.com/notebook/acme-tb01-7-inch-tablet-pc-reviews-specs-price-and-video-review.html) and I want to know if it will allow to speak over [Skype](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skype.raider&hl=en) using both front or back camera. Can I make video calls?

Comment: I'm surprised you'd try to buy this table considering the site you link says the following "Even less competitive with other tablets. Features in it are not worth the price in the offer." So long as Skype can run on Android 2.3 you should be able to use it. You really should use Google prior to asking such a question here.

Answer (score -1):

The current Skype Android app does not support video calling at all.

If it did, and your device ran the appropriate version of Android, you shouldn't have any problems.  However, just like using a desktop computer - your performance will be variable.  Using a less powerful device will result in a less optimal experience.

There is an alternative, using Google+ (and hangouts).  However, to use this, I am pretty sure you will need the Google custom libraries.  In that case, you need to check the device you are buying to see if it is marked as a "Google Experience" device.  This means it has the "blessing" to run Google apps.  Otherwise, the device is likely based on the Open Source version of Android, which is not as full featured.

Comment: Skype for Android supports video calling. They even advertise it [on their website](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-mobile/download/skype-for-android/).